# Can a Constructor be Private in C++?

Tags: c++

Can a constructor be private in C++? If yes then how can we call it?

```
class Puma
{
    int a = 10;
    Puma()
    {
        cout << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Puma pum;
    return o;
}
```

Can this program run? If not then how can we call `Puma()` constructor as it is private?

Comment: "can this program run" you didn't try to run it?

Comment: Removing `[java]` and `[c]` tags as the question doesn't appear to relate to those languages.

Comment: Yes, it can, and you can call it with a friend function/class or from within. I've used the technique to make an `Angle` class that could only be created with a `Degrees` or a `Radians`.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort". It's trivially easy to test this yourself.

Comment: @AbhishekJain, Because you haven't used a listed method to call it.

Comment: Thanx chris to solve my query..

Comment: yes meager... i do not do any research actually this question has been asked in interview today. and i am unable to answer..

Comment: @chris Named constructor idiom. Forgive me, but how will you then later safely know what is used. Better to have two different types to make the source type rich or to supply unit argument.

Comment: @Frodo: You don't need to know which is used.  The Angle class encapsulates the idea of an angle, and you have no direct access to the number that is stored inside.  You can call a `radians()` or a `degrees()` member function to get the value out as one of those.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Exactly, and the constructor argument is always in radians (which should be fine, seeing as how it's an implementation detail). The `Degrees` class converts its value in order to pass it.

Comment: @chris: I did something similar with every dimension I could think of. (Length, Area, Mass, Time, Energy, etc...)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Then you have taken care of that. But the often referenced online example is really bad: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html I now see that it is sadly enough referred to below on this page.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, a constructor can be private.  And you can call it with member functions (static or non) or friend functions.

```
class Puma
{
public:
    static Puma create(int a) { return Puma(a); }
private:
    int age;
    Puma(int a) :age(a) {}    

    friend Puma createPuma(int a);
};

Puma createPuma(int a) { return Puma(a); }
```

For possible use cases, see the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or the [Named Constructor Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom).

Comment: I would add the classical way of making a singleton. In that case you would use a static member for access.

Comment: @Frodo: I would append that with, "never make a singleton class, singleton classes are a terrible idea".

Comment: Not correct. There are definitely uses for true singleton, but you may equally well use namespaces or free functions in many cases. But there are misuses or overuses.

Comment: Just a noob question: How would you use the returned object inside friend function?
I mean, can we access/use the returned object inside `main`?

Also, Is there any use-case where we are creating an object through friend function/static function?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Constructor may be private.

In this case you may create class

- Using another (public) constructor
- Calling constructor from the same class
- Calling constructor from the friend class/function

Comment: Bonus for hinting at "why" you would do such a thing (AKA the factory model)

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the program cannot run since you have defined a constructor and it is private. Therefore, in your current code, there is no way to create objects of the class, making the class useless in a sense.

One way to do is that you can provide public static functions, those static functions call the private constructors to create objects of class.

One minor thing:

```
return o;
```

should be

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Can we create objects inside static functions with constructor being private?

Answer (score 2):

Yes a constructor can be private. It is useful when called by a static member function (or a friend), e.g.

```
 class Even {
  /// in practice, some more C++ code is probably needed
  private: 
    int x;
    Even(int a) : x(a) {};
  public:
     int get () const { return 2*x; }; 
     static Even* make(int y) { return new Even(y); };
  };
```

the example is not very realistic, but you get the idea. In the using code, do

```
   Even* e = Even::make(3);
```

Be however aware of the C++ [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and do read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org)) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). You may even want to use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

For examples, download, then look inside the source code of [Qt](https://qt.io/), of [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), of [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), of [fish](https://fishshell.com/), of  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org).

Comment: Interesting way to create an object via the other way.
 Just a noob question: Is there anything that we can achieve through this kind(creating object using the static or friend function) of object creation?

Answer (score 1):

Singleton can have a private constructor that will be called from a static method of a class.